# Identification of each tangent space $T_pV$ with $V$ itself?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I found this statement from my text very confusing:

> What does it mean by identification of each tangent space $T_pV$ with $V$ itself? - what does "identification" really mean here?

If it means isomorphic, then it conflicts with my understanding that each tangent space $T_pV$ is *locally* isomorphic to $V$.

> What is $Xf$? I don't understand the expression. I don't know what is the function $f$.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "Identification" means "pretend things are one and the same," which we're perfectly within our rights to do here because they *are* all isomorphic. Why do you think isomorphism "conflicts" with local isomorphism?

Comment: @anon, but the problem is how can we pretend? Consider $S^1$, we can't find correspondence between $S^1$ and the tangent space of $p \in S^1$.

Comment: But we're **not** considering $S^1$, the text says quite clearly we're specifically considering the situation where we have a vector space as a manifold, in which case *yes* there is a canonical isomorphism between $V$ and all of its points' tangent spaces. If a text for instance were to say "polynomials have derivatives as follows ..." the reaction "but it isn't possible to take derivatives of functions in general because they may not be differentiable" is out of place!

Comment: ok - then what is $Xf$? Thanks anon.

Comment: As the definition states, it is the directional derivative of $f$ with respect to the vector $X$.

Comment: @anon so $Xf$ actually is $df_X$...? And then what is $f$?

Comment: $f$ is any differentiable function we care to speak of.

Comment: I got all the components, thanks @anon. But I still don't know how the equation identifies $T_pV$ with $V$.. Is the rhs $T_pV$, and rhs $V$..?

Comment: Have you studied multivariable calculus before? In that subject, we talk about tangent vectors as elements of the space itself, and consider directional derivatives accordingly!

Comment: hmm, I studied multivariable calculus before, but still confused here....@anon..

Comment: What's your definition for $T_pV$?

Comment: @TTS the tangent space of $p$.

Comment: A translation of "identification" that you might like is "canonical isomorphism". Of course $T_pM$ is always isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$: one picks a chart and does some calculus. But there are many charts and they all give different isomorphisms. Whereas identifying vectors with directional derivatives doesn't involve any sort of choice.

Comment: @user83036 Not really what I meant! Okay, it seems as if your text defines $T_pM$ as the space of "derivations at $p$". So these are $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps $C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $X(fg) = (Xf)g(p) + f(p)(Xg)$ for $X \in T_pM$ and $f, g \in C^\infty(M)$. [I could replace $C^\infty(M)$ by the space of germs of $C^\infty$ functions at $p$. In the real $C^\infty$ case it doesn't matter.] So you need to check that the $X$ that's defined up there is this sort of map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is implicit in the author's comment is the view of a tangent vector as a linear functional on the space of smooth functions defined near $p$.

This is a somewhat roundabout way of thinking of a tangent vector, and it does not connect easily with intuition, but it can be efficient when you study smooth manifolds.

The author's point is that when the manifold happens to be a vector space $V$, there is a natural choice for such a functional, namely the one given by the formula $Xf = \frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}$, etc.  In this case the roundabout approach is clearly redundant, but it needs to be shown that it is consistent with what we expect it to be intuitively, namely the directional derivative.

Comment: (+1) Could a tangent space be a module over a ring (instead of a field) ?

Comment: @Esmond, this is (sort of) what algebraic geometry is about.  Since I am a differential geometer, I will let others answer your query.  I suggest you post it as a separate *question* (you can leave me a note if and when you do that).

Answer (score 3):

One can think of the tangent spaces as the "directions one can move" (which include both speed and direction, i.e. they are vectors) on a manifold at a point $p$. It's not hard to convince yourself that if you look at a point on a vector space (which you should think of as flat in some sense), the directions you can move correspond to all the vectors in the space. If I start at a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can move on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in any direction from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Not so if I start at a point on the two-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where I can move only in directions tangent to the two-sphere.

Now when you read "direction", you may replace it with "the operator on functions which is the directional derivative in that direction". Indeed, that is how geometers managed to make rigorous the notion of the directions you can move on a manifold at a given point.

Comment: (+1) Could a tangent space be a module over a ring (instead of a field) ? Nice answer by the way

Comment: @Esmond I don't know of a case where you'd call something the "tangent space" when it involves modules and not vector spaces, but there could be. The notion of "direction" in topology often involves an implicit dependence on the topology of the real line. To generalize, you might start with the term "fiber bundle", of which "tangent bundle" and "module bundle" are examples. Also related are sheaves. A fair amount of the mathematics of the 20th century involves various algebraic objects parameterized by topological spaces. Enjoy!