# Why is $e^{it}$ a submersion, and what is the relationship between the derivative $\dot h(t)$ and the differential $h_{*,t}$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-forms

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu.

In the paragraph below, why exactly is $h: \mathbb R \to S^1, h(t)=(\cos t, \sin t) \cong e^{it}$ a submersion, and what is the relationship between the derivative $\dot h(t) = (-\sin t, \cos t) \cong ie^{it}$ and the differential $h_{*,t}$?

[image]

My argument is that the image of the differential at any $t$, $h_{*,t}: T_t(\mathbb R) \to T_{e^{it}}(S^1)$, is a vector subspace of $S^1$, which has dimension 1, so the image has dimension either $0$ or $1$, so the differential is either trivial or surjective. I think I can show each $h_{*,t}$ is not trivial directly by computing the image:

$$im(h_{*,t}) = h_{*,t}(T_t(\mathbb R)) = \{h_{*,t}(a \frac{d}{dt})\}_{a \in \mathbb R} = \{ah_{*,t}(\frac{d}{dt})\}_{a \in \mathbb R}$$

$$\ne \{\text{the zero element of} \ T_{e^{it}}(S^1) \ \text{which I think corresponds to the point} \ 1+0i \in S^1 \}$$

I cannot seem to identify the precise relationship between the derivative $\dot h(t)$ and the differential $h_{*,t}$, which I think I would assume in proving the preceding inequality. For a function $f: M \to \mathbb R$, there is a relationship between $f$'s a submersion at $p$ and $f$'s partial derivatives, but now we have $f: \mathbb R \to M$.

---

**[Update](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305351/in-proving-cist-eit-a-submersion-is-dot-ht-actually-dot-gt)**: My answer considers the inclusion $g = \iota \circ h$ of $h$ into $\mathbb R^2$. After all, we have in the first place that $h$ is smooth by [Theorem 11.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuCpy.png) because $g$ is smooth.

1. For such inclusion $g = \iota \circ h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$, $g(t_0) = (\iota \circ h)(t_0) = \iota(h(t_0))=h(t_0), \iota: S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$, we have by chain rule that for each $t_0 \in \mathbb R$, $g_{*,t_0}: T_{t_0}\mathbb R \to T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$ is given by $g_{*,t_0} = \iota_{*,h(t_0)} \circ h_{*,t_0}$.
2. For each $t_0 \in \mathbb R$, $\iota_{*,h(t_0)}: T_{h(t_0)}S^1 \to T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$ is still inclusion so $\iota_{*,h(t_0)} \circ h_{*,t_0} = h_{*,t_0}$
3. Let $t_0 \in \mathbb R$. If $h_{*,t_0}$ is not the zero map, then $h_{*,t_0}$ is surjective because the image of $h_{*,t_0}: T_{t_0}\mathbb R \to T_{h(t_0)}S^1$ is a subspace of $T_{h(t_0)}S^1 \cong \mathbb R$ and thus is (isomorphic to) either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^0 = \{0\}$.
4. Now, I'll argue that $h_{*,t_0}$ is not the zero map if I can show that $g_{*,t_0}$ is not the zero map since $T_{h(t_0)}S^1$ and $T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$ share the same zero element since $T_{h(t_0)}S^1$ is a vector subspace of $T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$.
5. $g_{*,t_0}$ is not the zero map if the geometric derivative (or velocity vector) $g'(t_0) := g_{*,t_0}[\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}]$ is not the zero vector i.e. if $g_{*,t_0}$ maps the basis element of $T_{t_0}\mathbb R$ to a nonzero element of $T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$.
6. Finally, $g'(t_0)$, by [Proposition 8.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21tS.png), is represented by calculus derivative $\dot g(t) = (-\sin(t),\cos(t))$ through $g'(t_0) = -\sin(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1} + \cos(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial r^2}$, where $r^1$ and $r^2$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r^1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r^2} \}$ forms a basis for $T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$.
7. By (6), $g'(t_0)$ is not the zero vector of $T_{h(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$.
8. Therefore, by (7),(5),(4) $g_{*,t_0}$ is the not the zero map.
9. Therefore, by (3) and (8), neither is $h_{*,t_0}$ i.e. $h'(t_0)$ is the not the zero vector of $T_{h(t_0)}S^1$.

Comment: because i did not think it was relatable to the question. And also why are you asking about it in my prev question

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't seem to find any geometrical application in this question.

Comment: @rash How are submersions, point-derivations and differential forms not relevant to geometry? Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Just because you didn't see any relevance doesn't mean there isn't relevance right?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1-dimensional vector space $T_t(\mathbb R)$ the standard basis element, as you seem to have noticed, is $\frac{d}{dt}$.

At $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, the 1-dimensional vector space $T_{(\cos(t),\sin(t))} S^1$ has standard basis element $(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$.

In both cases, by "standard" I mean that the basis element has length 1 with respect to the "usual" norm, and it points in the direction of the "standard" orientation.

The relationship between $\dot h(t)$ and the differential $h_{*,t}$ is 
$$h_{*,t}(a \frac{d}{dt}) = a h_*(\frac{d}{dt}) = a (-sin(t),\cos(t)) = (-a\sin(t),a\cos(t))
$$

Comment: Thanks! 1. Do you use the [isomorphism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21tS.png) between the coefficient in the velocity vector $h'$ and the derivative $\dot h$, so precisely we have $h'(t) \cong (-\sin(t),\cos(t))$? 2.abcd Does that mean in the [definition of a smooth curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omGeX.png), $a$ and $b$ are actually extended real numbers?

Comment: 3. So it is in fact important to point out that the image is of the differential is a vector subspace of a 1-dimensional vector space (which Tu does not do, but which Tu did for [Proposition 8.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEBBL.png))? 4. What exactly does the non-$(0,0)$ have to do with anything?  mean what does the $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$ have to do with the range $S^1$ ? I think we should be focusing on the $0 \in T_{e^{it}}(S^1)$, which I think corresponds (by the isomorphism $S^1 \cong T_{e^{it}}(S^1)$) to $1+0i$.

Comment: I edited my question with the answer I had come up with. Is it correct please?

Comment: Is it really correct to say that that's $h'(t_0)$ instead of $g'(t_0)$? Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305351/prove-eit-a-submersion-different-proof-is-dot-ht-actually-dot-g)

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the difference between $h'(t_0)$ and $h_{*,t_0}$, 
$$ h_{*,t_0}\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(h)\bigg|_{t_0}=h'(t_0).$$
In particular, the differential map $h_{*,t_0}$ is a linear map $h_{*,t_0}: T_{t_0} \mathbb{R}\to T_{h(t_0)}S^1$. $h'(t_0)$ is the image of the tangent vector 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_t\in T_t\mathbb{R}.$$
As for  this problem: because we have a linear map $h_{*,t_0}$ between one-dimensional vector spaces the image is all of the vector space so long as the transformation does not send $d/dt|_{t_0}\in T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}$ to $0$. For $t_0$, we have 
$$ h_{*,t_0}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t_0}=h'(t_0)=(-\sin t_0,\cos t_0).$$
A brief argument will show that $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are never simultaneously zero. So, $h'(t_0)$ is never the zero vector, hence $h_*$ is always surjective, so $h$ is a submersion.

Comment: Thanks! 1. Do you use the [isomorphism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21tS.png) between the coefficient in the velocity vector $h'$ and the derivative $\dot h$, so precisely we have $h'(t) \cong (-\sin(t),\cos(t))$? 2.abcd Does that mean in the [definition of a smooth curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omGeX.png), $a$ and $b$ are actually extended real numbers?

Comment: 3. So it is in fact important to point out that the image is of the differential is a vector subspace of a 1-dimensional vector space (which Tu does not do, but which Tu did for [Proposition 8.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEBBL.png))? 4. What exactly is $0$? Do you mean $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$ (or $0+0i \in \mathbb C$)? I'd think you mean $0 \in T_{e^{it}}(S^1)$, which I think corresponds (by the isomorphism $S^1 \cong T_{e^{it}}(S^1)$) to $1+0i$. If you mean $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$, then why exactly? I mean what does the $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$ have to do with the range $S^1$ ?

Comment: 1. I don't know if saying $h'(t)\cong (-\sin t , \cos t)$ is meaningful, but I am using that proposition. 2. They are extended real numbers in the sense that $a,b$ can equal $\pm\infty$. 3. This is clear from the context; $T_pS^1$ is one-dimensional because $S^1$ is a 1-dimensional manifold, and the differential map is linear. 4. I mean $0\in T_pS^1$.

Comment: Since you mean $0\in T_tS^1$ (I'll use $t$ instead of $p$), what about $t = -\pi/2$ ? I think $(-\sin(-\pi/2),\cos(-\pi/2))=(1,0)$, and the $(1,0) \in S^1$ corresponds to the $0\in T_tS^1$ (I think for any $t$ actually). Thanks!

Comment: That's not quite right. At $t=-\pi/2$ the vector you get is a nonzero element of the tangent space.

Comment: I actually don't really know the isomorphism between $S^1 \cong T_tS^1$. What is it please? Does the $0 \in T_tS^1$ correspond to different elements of $S^1$ depending on the $t$? Or are they actually not isomorphic and just simply have the same dimension?

Comment: Oh I think $S^1$ [would be isomorphic to its tangent spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430426/identification-of-each-tangent-space-t-pv-with-v-itself) if $S^1$ were a vector space. Oh I think I kinda get it, $T_tS^1 \ncong S^1$, but $T_tS^1 \cong \mathbb R$, so the $0 \in \mathbb R$ corresponds to both the $0 \in T_tS^1$?

Comment: Wait but we're trying to show $h'$ is never $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$ right? How does this mean that $h_{*,t}[\frac{d}{dt}]$ is never the $0 \in T_tS^1$? I am so confused.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, as I say it in the interest of helping: you need to review the constructions involving tangent spaces etc. before you have a good chance of understanding differential forms. If you review that material this probably won't be difficult anymore.

Comment: I don't think there's another way to take that. Thanks!

Comment: I think I have come up with answer. I'll post later.

Comment: I edited my question with the answer I had come up with. Is it correct please?

Comment: Is it really correct to say that that's $h'(t_0)$ instead of $g'(t_0)$? Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305351/prove-eit-a-submersion-different-proof-is-dot-ht-actually-dot-g)

Comment: Antonios-Alexandros Robotis, you said "you need to review the constructions involving tangent spaces etc." I believe there may an error in the book as I indicate in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305351/in-proving-cist-eit-a-submersion-is-dot-ht-actually-dot-gt). Do you disagree in that it's on me to review rather than on the book to make a correction?